# Rails3 app not recognizing defined action/route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-routing

The following route is defined:

```
resources :products do
  collection do
    get :confirm
  end
  member do
    put :confirmed
  end
end
```

and `rake:routes` returns:

```
confirmed_product PUT    /products/:id/confirmed(.:format)  products#confirmed
```

The controller has a defined action:

```
def confirmed
  @product = Product(params[:id])
  @product.update_column(:paymentstate_id, "1")
  render :action => "confirmed"
end
```

The model's helper actually defines:

```
'http://' + @site.host + confirmed_product_path(@product)
```

Yet, upon posting of information to this page (from an external source, as this is the return of a checkout payment), the data DOES return to

```
[host]/products/2/confirmed
```

But with the error:

```
Unknown action
The action '2' could not be found for ProductsController
```

I expected the 'member' item would have allowed for 2 to be recognized as the `id` and generate the confirmed action, as the `rake routes` attests.

Comment: Make sure your form is doing a PUT and not a POST as is default, otherwise your route wont be matched.

Comment: good thinking  I was assuming the data trasmission as a put. Route now changed and functioning

Comment: I'll move my comment over to an answer for you then ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your form is doing a PUT and not a POST as is default, otherwise your route wont be matched.

Answer (score 3):

When the URL is correct (if a helper generates an URL, you can take that it's gonna be correct) but you can't access it somehow, always check the HTTP verb.

Also, `'http://' + @site.host + confirmed_product_path(@product)` is available in rails as `confirmed_product_url(@product)` (note the `_url` at the end).

Last, `render action: 'foo'` can be written `render 'foo'`